# angular 2 how to render multiple components in isolation?

Tags: templates, angular, error-handling, rendering

Suppose I have a big component that has multiple smaller components. Each small component has its own template and rendering logic. Any of these components could fail to render, e.g. errors / exceptions thrown from the .html template. What I'm looking for is a general strategy in Angular 2 to keep these components' rendering in complete isolation without hand coding lots of validation code. Is there a way to catch exceptions from .html file and deal with them in .ts?